# How to create google server api key in recent google api console?

Tags: android, google-api

I want to create google server api key to use google maps road api. But at recent google api console, I couldn't see this page.

[image: oldc]

But My console is this.

[image: mycons]

Please, give a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google recently removed the concept of a key type. The new key that you see in the Google API Console will work with the Google Maps Roads API in the same way that an old server key would. If you wish to restrict the key to specific severs, you can enter IP address restrictions for the key as you could before.

Comment: But I want to no restrict in api key. I've seen old version could create without restrict. But recent version, it have to restrict specific IP Adress. How do I do?

Comment: A key is unrestricted when you first create it. You can also choose the top radio button under Key Restrictions, None, and then ignore the yellow triangle warning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But when I choose none restriction, the response data is null. You know what happen?

Comment: Hmm, I would need a few more details. How are you calling the API? Are there any error details in the response?

Comment: Ahh.. I succeed snap to road. But doesn't Road API services in Korea ? I want to service my application, in Korea.

Comment: If it can't, any ways are exist?